# Cannot get the child of a GameObject through script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to access the animator component of my player character. The character is spawned under the GameObject `Character position`, which it self is the child of `Game Manager`.

The character prefabs have various names, so I cannot find them through exact name. So its easier to just get the only child of `Character position`.

```
Game Manager
  Character position
    Player Prefab
```

Ive searched online and tried `GetChild` by index and `GetComponentInChildren`. None of them work. Below is the script I wrote for this:

```
    private Animator archerAnimator;
    private float startSpeed;

    GameObject charPos;
    GameObject archer_;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        charPos = GameObject.Find("Game manager/Character position");
        Debug.Log(charPos);
        archer_ = charPos.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
        archerAnimator = charPos.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
        Debug.Log(archerAnimator);
    }
```

`charPos` is found, but for `archer_` I get the error, `Transform child out of bounds`. The player archer is not there but is spawned at run time when the scene starts, is this the reason it cannot find it so quickly?

Some guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: So the problem is your trying to find a game object that does not exist yet?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Thats what I think may be happening. As the player is spawned as soon as the game starts. Maybe I'm trying to find it before its spawned. How to resolve this?

Comment: Show how  ans where you're spawning the character via code. Also show the Hierarchy tab screenshot that shows the character when you spawn it

Comment: When you have some actions related to each others but are not in the same script, avoid declaring your logic in the start function, because if you are Instantiating the object and its children in another script within the start method, you can't guarantee or know which start will be triggered first. Instead, you can declare starting logic in an Init() function and then call them in order in the manager.
(Another way to fix this without using the solution above is to change the execution order rules in Unity)
Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're scanning for the player too early. You should reverse your discovery logic. Instead of scanning for the player and its Animator, you should put a script on the player itself that runs after it is created and reports itself to the game manager or whatever object needs access to it, something like this:

```
void Start() { GetComponentInParent<GameManager>().OnPlayerSpawned(this); }
```

I'll also mention that some script finding an object by name and accessing its components is a generally bad idea. Here's a design guideline to always keep in mind: **You should traverse Unity's object hierarchy as infrequently as possible, and even if you do, you should only traverse objects that don't have other scripts attached.** In this case, you should also put the logic to control the Animator inside your `Player` script. Then, you wouldn't need to get a reference to the Animator in the first place.